# WordPress исчезает логотип в шапке на мобильной версии сайта при загрузке страницы

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Всем привет!! Помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять почему не показывает логотип в шапке. Сайт: https://highmax.md/?page_id=99.

Comment: Вместо ссылки на сайт покажите неработающий код.

Answer (score 0):

У вас там srcset кривой.

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/logo_white_fara-150x150.png" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="" loading="lazy" srcset="https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/logo_white_fara-150x150.png 150w, https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/elementor/thumbs/logo_white_fara-pwc7cou291r8t7dkx36drchetzk8bh8dgjpewf3ooo.png 300w, https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/logo_white_fara-1024x1024.png 1024w, https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/logo_white_fara-768x768.png 768w, https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/elementor/thumbs/logo_white_fara-pwc7cou4orc417p1qwwpzi64wnzhmznt84vr7824qw.png 500w, https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/elementor/thumbs/logo_white_fara-pwc7cou6mxeem0r0t6ald8bikeq3hssyn0811gtoso.png 660w, https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/elementor/thumbs/logo_white_fara-pwc7cou6ijirg7xnda7h5mfogoaxmmhe1trifbrysk.png 650w, https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/elementor/thumbs/logo_white_fara-pwc7cou5aoqbu7rwydcb1jlbfc3ayv9o616c9xaqrg.png 550w, https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/logo_white_fara.png 1280w" sizes="(max-width: 150px) 100vw, 150px">
```

При разрешении экрана до 660px в ширину должно быть использовано изображение `https://highmax.md/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/elementor/thumbs/logo_white_fara-pwc7cou6mxeem0r0t6ald8bikeq3hssyn0811gtoso.png` а оно не существует.

Деактивируйте плагины "оптимизации", пересоздайте миниатюры и всё будет работать.

Comment: А у меня нет плагины "оптимизации". я делал страницы через elementor.